# batch listing all active ip addresses

Tags: networking, batch, ip

I searched for this, then I tried to create a batch file to no avail.
I have a great program (netwatcher) that gathers active IPs (using the arp table) in one address range only, but I have subnets too.

I can't figure out how to break out the arp table and only display ips and not the rest of the information, while trying to resolve the name.

I can use angry ip or netwatcher and set to scan the entire range, but wanted to add this batch to another batch utility I already made.
I'm using batch so I can walk up to any network and scan without installing or adding a program.

Comment: Welcome to SU!  What's your question to us exactly?  While we're not a script-writing service, we can help with specifics, but we'll need information from you. What have you got/tried already?  What were the results?

Comment: Start with `for /f "tokens=1-4" %G in ('arp -a') do @echo G=%G H=%H I=%I J=%J` from command prompt to see an initial look. [Learn more](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html). Feel free to [update your question](http://superuser.com/posts/865109/edit) if you crane at something.